# Scaling and Labelling KDE plots

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I plotted PDF using *kdeplot*. I am having a tough time to scale and label the plots.

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

error = np.array([1,2,2,3,4,4,5])
error2 = np.array([3,3,4,4,4,6])
sns.kdeplot(error, color='blue',label='error')
sns.kdeplot(error2, color='red',label='error2')
plt.show()
```

[image]

I want the blue curve to be labelled as 'error' and red curve to be labelled as 'error2'.
Also, I want to scale the y-axis. It should be in the range of 0 to 1 with 0.1 interval. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `plt.legend()`, `plt.ylim(0,1)` should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

To add a legend, just add

```
plt.legend()
```

above `plt.show()`. To set the limit of the axis, use

```
ax = plt.gca() # get current axis
ax.set_ylim([0, 1])
```

To set the ticks accordingly, you can use

```
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.1))
```

(All above `plt.show()`)